# Laravel can't find Carbon package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to change the 'duration' of my Laravel passport jwt tokens as explain in the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#token-lifetimes)

but when I hover on a carbon function like `addDays()` my IDE says:
`Method 'addDays' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Carbon`

even if I try to `use Carbon\Carbon` package it says that Laravel can't find the package.

I also noticed that if I go to definition of the Carbon class inside `Illuminate\Support`it can't extend the `BaseCarbon` class

any help? here is my AuthServiceProvider.php file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;



class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::hashClientSecrets();
        Passport::loadKeysFrom(__DIR__.'/../secrets/oauth');

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(6));

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in your application that you're seeing, or is it just your IDE?

Comment: just the ice I'm using PhpStorm

Comment: You might want to take a look at this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper. It can help with a lot of the IDE squiggles you'll get

Comment: use Carbon\Carbon;

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

> now()->addDays(30)

to

> Carbon::now()->addDays(30)